# IE z-index and position problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have IE 8 and IE 7 `z-index`, `position` and other problems.  I've made an example of these problems at http://jsfiddle.net/KeEPF/.  If you look at it through Chrome, Mozilla or another browser, you would notice the big image has links on top of it (with link `#imagemap2`).
On IE8 and IE7 this image is always on top and you can not click the links.

How can I fix this problem?

Here is the code:

```
<div id="splashbar"> 
    <div id="left_content_text"> 
        <img src="#" alt="facebook" /> 
        <h2> <a href="" style="color:#fff; text-decoration:none;">test</a></h2> 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, con tetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tincidu molestie justo, vitae dignissim me scelerisque vel. Proin vitae nibh arcu vulpu tate vehicula.<br/> 
    </div> 
    <div id="splashimages"> 
        <a href="#full_header_link" class="full_header_link"> 
            <img width="738" height="191" src="tet" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="header_forside" title="header_forside" />                                            </a> 
        <a href="#imagemap1" style="width:100px;height:100px;left:0px; top:10px" class="imagemap_header_link"> </a> 
        <a href="#imagemap2" style="width:100px;height:100px;right:0px; top:10px" class="imagemap_header_link"></a> 
    </div> 
    <div class="clear"> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

```
#splashbar {
    position: relative;
    zoom: 1;
    z-index: 2;
}
#splashimages {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    zoom: 1;
}
#splashimages img {
    z-index: -5;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    height: 173px;
    zoom: 1;
}
#splashimages .imagemap_header_link {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    z-index: 990;
    visibility: visible;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: You have mixed inline styles with external styles, fix this first. Some properties are duplicated and other selectors aren't even included in your example. Accurate examples are the first step to a solution.

Comment: Actually all selectors are included. It works in fiddle in chrome, mozzila or etc. But not ie... Also i am using it with some custom fields and etc in CMS so i have to mix inline css with external, it is only way to do it .. Maybe anyone see, how this could be fixed ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it can be fixed with a bit of a cheat..

IE doesn't like the fact that there is no background on your 2 "imagemap" links, though I presume you want them transparent as that's the idea of the map

this works for me:

```
#splashimages .imagemap_header_link {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 10px;

  background: #dad; /* any color */
  filter:alpha(opacity=0); /* make it transparent in IE again */
  opacity: 0; /* make it transparent for good browsers */
}
```

#### [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/B5KQZ/)

added: for the record the working example has removed all unnecessary extra properties, there no need to set `zoom: 1;` on any of the divs, the absolutely positioned ones already have "hasLayout"

Comment: THANKS !!! have not think about such solution ! thanks :D really worked perfectly and how i wanted ! Thanks

Comment: Setting filter:alpha(opacity=0) works for most situations, but not if you have other elements inside the link. In this case setting background:url(#) or using a transparent gif/png is the only fix.

Comment: Also +1 for the comment `/* make it transparent for good browsers */`